# How do I allow my Typedef Struct to Add, Subtract, Multiply and Divide?

Tags: objective-c, math, struct, typedef

I want to be able to use math functions on my "vector3D"s like so

```
vector3D a = v3d(1.0,1.0,1.0);
vector3D b = v3d(2.0,0.0,5.0);

a+=b;
vector3D c = a*b;
```

The code for my typedef struct:

```
typedef struct _vector3D{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}vector3D;


static inline vector3D
v3d(const float x, const float y, const float z)
{
    vector3D v = {x,y,z};
    return v;
}
```

How do I allow my typedef struct vector3D to handle this operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C, and therefore Objective-C, does not support method overloading.
You'll have to write your own `add` and `multiply` functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, a struct can't have methods at all. You would have to use normal C functions like `vector3D add(vector3D, vector3D)`, etc. to perform the functionality.

You could use Objective-C classes and define similar methods on them, but you should be terribly aware of lifetime issues, especially WRT intermediate results in more complex expressions with nested "method calls". Who will release the intermediate? Is autorelease any good in such situations? Etc. These are the questions you will have to ask yourself.